# GUI for using Hadoop

Tags: user-interface, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hue

Is there an easy way to use Hadoop other than with the command line?

Which tools are you using and which one is the best?

Answer (score 7):

Hue is pretty cool, new features are regularly pushed out and it's open source.

From its [website](http://gethue.com):
Hue features a File Browser for HDFS, a Job Designer/Browser for MapReduce, query editors for Hive, Pig, Cloudera Impala and Solr Search.
It also ships with an Oozie Application for creating workflows, various Shells and a collection of Hadoop API.

Comment: can we use Hue without CDH's implementation of hadoop? I meant, could we install/download the official hadoop package from apache, install it and get it working with Hue?

Comment: Hue is open source (https://github.com/cloudera/hue) and works with vanilla Hadoop and some Cloudera competitors distributions. They are some examples on the Hue group: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!searchin/hue-user/apache$20hadoop

Obviously, the integration/testing/support is better with CDH.

Comment: Hue works well with CDH/HDP/vanilla hadoop. There's no any limitations or dependency on hadoop internals, it uses only external APIs. Only Hive/Beeswax may have issues, but should be ok.

Answer (score 3):

Although Enrico already answered the question, I would like to add few points to that.

Hue is a really amazing tool and we have been using it at Goibibo.com for last 1 year. We have exposed it to developers and business people for running their hive queries and getting results.

Also we are indexing log data so cloudera search comes in pretty handy. With the new version of Hue (3.6), you can also run queries on RDBMS data using HUE itself.

I would really recommend using it because its really simple to use and provides a GUI to mostly everything there in the bigdata ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows, you can use an open source project called [HDFS Explorer](https://github.com/SaschaDittmann/HdfsExplorer).

If you're on a Mac or Linux, then you can mount Hadoop filesystems directly using FUSE, and then use Finder, or Nautilus, or whatever you normally use for filesystem navigation. Checkout the Hadoop wiki on how to setup the mounts http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS

Each distribution provides a web based GUI, in some cases Hue, and in others based on the new Ambari views framework, which provide access to file functionality.

Comment: Looks like you are no longer offering HDFS Explorer?

Comment: I've actually left Red Gate. They have since exited the Hadoop market. I will update the answer, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for some Data Integration tools like Talend, CloverETL or Pentaho. They have provided support for Hadoop.Talend has provided a vast support of it. Don't have much information about the other tools support for Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for something a step up from the cli for exploring, my installation has a web server that installed with hadoop and it is accessible at :50075. The port is configurable, but give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDH, then Hue(hadoop user Interface) comes with it. And its a very good user interface for hadoop. You can also use install separately. It supports all components of hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a light-weight Hadoop file manager [HFX](https://github.com/siyanew/HFX). You can use this. It has some essential features like drag and drop, upload, cut, copy and paste...